# Issue with open a Popup / Dialog box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamic select box in my application. On click of any list item I need to show the item details in popup. But I'm unable to open the popup/dialog box which is not happening now, my code is,

```
 $( "#locationList" ).on( "click", "li", function( event ) { 
   alert("click event");
   $.mobile.changePage('#myPopupDialog', 'pop', true, true);
});
```

I'm able to see the alert, but dialog box is not opening.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>List Item details</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2>Welcome to my Popup Dialog!</h2>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

List elements should come dynamically from Db, like,

```
var optionheading = '<li value="Select Location">Select Location</li>';
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++)
            {
               var opt  = '<li value="';
               opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
               opt += '">';
               opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
               opt += '</li>';
               $("#locationList").append(opt);
            }
          $("#locationList").listview('refresh');
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" data-dismissible="false" style="height: 150px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#f2f2f2;font:normal 11px/15px arial;padding:6px;color:#333; overflow: auto" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
                </ul>
```

any suggestions!!

Comment: Neither of the elements mentioned in your JS are in the HTML snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear with your statement

Comment: What @IanClark is saying is : where is `locationList` element in your HTML

Comment: It is in some other my home page. But I wrote the dialog out of that page

Comment: You should post the HTML relevant to your JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog has

```
id="dialog"
```

However your javascript is trying to popup a dialog with an id of myPopupDialog:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#myPopupDialog', 'pop', true, true);
```

These IDs must match!

If you are using jQM 1.4.x, your dialog page should use data-dialog="true":

```
<div data-dialog="true" id="myPopupDialog">
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4K9k4/)**

Comment: Yes I need the same, But How can I display the popup at center to the mobile screen

Comment: @Precious, you could use the popup widget instead of the dialog page: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/popup/, setting data-position-to="window" centers it in the page.

Comment: @Precious, here is updated fiddle using popup: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4K9k4/1/

Comment: But Where should I need to write popup. In the same page tag or out side to the page tag?

Comment: @Precious, look at my jsfiddle, the popup markup goes within the page div at the same level as header/content/footer div. For readability, I put it after the those divs before the closing tag of the page div. You can then dynamically set the content of the popup as needed based on which li you click.